# How to crop a CameraImage (Y'UV 420) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, crop

I am struggling to effectively crop a region of interest, i.e a bounding box extend on the CameraImage type, I have image coordinate parameters that defines the area of interest in the image plane, I'd be extremely happy if anyone can help with a solution that effectively take into consideration all the planes of Y', U and V of the cameraImage, resulting in a color image.
Thanks in advance, your help is much appreciated.

For now, I doing something like this and looks like it doesn't work.

```
Uint8List cropROI(CameraImage cameraImage){
  int divider = 1;
  int cropTop = 30;
  int cropBottom = 100;
  int cropLeft = 140;
  int cropRight = 42;
  final WriteBuffer allBytes = WriteBuffer();
  for (final Plane plane in cameraImage.planes) {
    for (int i = cropTop ~/ divider; i < cropBottom ~/ divider; i++) {
      for (int j = cropLeft ~/ divider; j < cropRight ~/ divider; j++) {
        allBytes.putUint8(plane.bytes[j + i * cameraImage.width ~/ divider]);
      }
    }
    divider = 2; // for planes U and V
  }
  return allBytes.done().buffer.asUint8List();
}
```

Ideally, the resulting cropped area of interest should be a colourImage.